# React Redux GeoFire object - how to correctly 'pass around' the geofire object and detect changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, geofire

I have a React app that uses Firebase and GeoFire to detect and save a user's geolocation. I have a react-redux set up that has worked great for everything I have done so far except in this case. I successfully set and 'return' a redux property for the GeoFire object. My user-geofire-actions.js looks like this:

```
import GeoFireUtil from '../firebase/GeoFireUtil';

export const GET_USER_GEOLOCATION = 'get_user_geolocation';

export function getUserGeoLocation(userId) {

    return dispatch => {

        try {

            // geofire stuff
            let geoFireUtil = new GeoFireUtil(userId);
            geoFireUtil.getLocation();
            localStorage.setItem('userGeoLocation', JSON.stringify(geoFireUtil));

            dispatch({
                type: GET_USER_GEOLOCATION,
                payload: geoFireUtil
            });

        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }

}
```

GeoFireUtil.js is a class where I wanted to control the GeoFire stuff from in a more practical manner (and be able to reuse if needed). This works great to set the right properties and detect the user and save it to the firebase database. An event gets set where if user leaves the app, refreshes the window, closes browser then it removes the geofire value from the firebase DB (and this is where the problems start):

```
// Initialize Firebase
import firebase, { geoLocationDatabase } from './firebase-connection';
import GeoFire from 'geofire';

// geofire connection ##################

class GeoFireUtil {

    constructor(userId, username) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.geoLocationRef = firebase.database().ref(geoLocationDatabase).push();
        this.geoFire = new GeoFire(this.geoLocationRef);
        this.geoCoordinates = null;
        this.geoRadius = 5;

        this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
        this.geolocationCallback = this.geolocationCallback.bind(this);
        this.removeLocation = this.removeLocation.bind(this);
        this.findNearbyUsers = this.findNearbyUsers.bind(this);
    }

    removeLocation() {
        console.log('in geofireutil removeLocation', this.userId);
        this.geoFire.remove(this.userId).then(() => {
            console.log('removed!!!');
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('error: ', error);
        });
    }

    findNearbyUsers() {
        let geoQuery = this.geoFire.query({
            center: this.geoCoordinates,
            radius: this.geoRadius
        });

        geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
            console.log('user keys', key);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Uses the HTML5 geolocation API to get the current user's location
     */
    getLocation() {
        if (typeof navigator !== 'undefined'
                && typeof navigator.geolocation !== 'undefined') {

            console.log('Asking user to get their location');
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                this.geolocationCallback,
                this.errorHandler
            );
            console.log('done', this.geoCoordinates);

        } else {
            console.log('Your browser does not support GPS detection - you need to use a different browser to use BBaq.');
        }
    };

    /**
     * Callback method from the geolocation API which receives
     * the current user's location
     *
     * @param      {<type>}  location  The location
     */
    geolocationCallback(location) {
        let latitude = location.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = location.coords.longitude;
        this.geoCoordinates = [latitude, longitude];

        console.log('Retrieved user\'s location: [' + latitude + ', ' + longitude + ']');

        this.geoFire.set(
            this.userId,
            [latitude, longitude]
        ).then(() => {
            console.log('Current user ' + this.userId + '\'s location has been added to GeoFire');

            // When the user disconnects from Firebase (e.g. closes the app,
            // exits the browser), remove their GeoFire entry
            this.geoLocationRef.child(this.userId).onDisconnect().remove();

            console.log('Added handler to remove user ' + this.userId + ' from GeoFire when you leave this page.');

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error adding user ' + this.userId + '\'s location to GeoFire');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Handles any errors from trying to get the user's current location
     *
     * @param      {<type>}  error   The error
     */
    errorHandler(error) {
        if (error.code === 1) {
            console.log('Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: User denied access to their location');
        } else if (error.code === 2) {
            console.log('Error: POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: Network is down or positioning satellites cannot be reached');
        } else if (error.code === 3) {
            console.log('Error: TIMEOUT: Calculating the user\'s location too took long');
        } else {
            console.log('Unexpected error code')
        }
    }

}

export default GeoFireUtil;
```

Again the above works great - but let's say I refresh the page or go directly to URL where I want to perform the geofire query to get users nearby I need to reload and detect the geo location all over again - this is fine I do this in MainApp that encapsulate my entire app (this is the parent component from which all other components rendered).

In my MainApp componentWillMount I do the following, and this works great - the problem is that I have a child component that continues rendering since JS is asynchronous:

```
componentWillMount() {
        // this is only for when the page is reloaded or url copied/pasted and 
        // we do not have any user info yet - if user is stored in the localStorage
        // but this.props.user redux object is not set yet, then get the user
        // to set everything - this should only happen on page load
        let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        if (this.props.user.loading === true && user) {
            this.props.getUser();
            // geofire gps location of user
            this.props.getUserGeoLocation(user.uid);
        }
    }
```

So, at this point the user's geolocation is still being detected, however in a child component which I have hooked up to redux correctly (I think) I need to make a call to a function in the GeoFireUtil.php that depends on parameters that are still yet to be set in the MainApp componentWillMount call to this.props.getUserGeoLocation(user.uid); and this causes undefined errors to appear.

I guess I'm stuck - how can i wait for the above to finish executing before child component makes a call on a property that requires certain parameters to be set before hand?

Here is the child component to query the locations near logged in user:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUserGeoLocation } from '../actions/user-geofire-actions';

class Friends extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            usersLoaded: false
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('about to receive props', nextProps.userGeoFire);
        if (nextProps.userGeoFire && nextProps.userGeoFire.geoCoordinates) {
            // the following errors out because this function requires certain parameters
            // be set before hand (and are still being set in MainApp componentWillMOunt)
            let nearbyUsers = this.props.userGeoFire.findNearbyUsers();
            console.log(nearbyUsers);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Friends Near You</h1>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//export default Header;
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.user,
        userGeoFire: state.userGeoFire
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserGeoLocation })(Friends);
```

Comment: Share your errors instead all the code you are using. You need to delimit the code not working.

Comment: I have no errors anymore because if you look in the Friends class above I in the componentWillReceiveProps() I'm first checking for certain parameters before proceeding - but this component never rerenders as I expected once MainApp has finished with geolocation related code - I have found this link and it seems the redux is not meant for 'deep' comparison of state properties and putting object like my GeoFireUtil. js is discouraged https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable.

Comment: If I am doing it wrong, then how do I keep track of my user's geolocation through out my app even when there is a page reload?